# Numpy 2d array, clipping each index of each row to the minimum of that index and a specific column

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 2d array, I want to take a specific column of that array.

I then want to take every value of each row in the array, and change that value to whatever the minimum is between its current value, and the value in the specified column *for that row* is.

What is an efficient way to do this?  Thank you.

Here is an example:

Given a 3x3 matrix:

```
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 8],
       [3, 7, 11]])
```

And a chosen column = column 2

```
array([2, 2, 7])
```

For every value in the matrix I take the minimum between that value and the value in the corresponding row of the chosen column

```
= [1, 2, 1; 2, 2, 2; 3, 7, 7]
```

How can I efficiently do this for a large matrix?  Thank you.

Comment: Please share a sample array and expected output

Comment: Use `np.minimum(a, a[:, col, None])`, where `col` is the index of your comparison column

Comment: I am not sure what I did... i somehow edited my original matrix.  You're right, what was posted does not make sense. But you completely answered my question anyways, could you place it as an answer so I can give you credit for answering?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.minimum`.  You need to broadcast to keep the dimensions of the column so you aren't comparing row-wise with the entire column.

```
np.minimum(a, a[:, col, None])
```

---

***MCVE***

```
a = np.array([[1, 3, 1, 9, 4],
              [2, 3, 7, 5, 5],
              [9, 8, 8, 4, 5],
              [6, 9, 5, 7, 9],
              [9, 9, 1, 9, 1]])

col = 2       # array([1, 7, 8, 5, 1])

np.minimum(a, a[:, col, None])
```

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 3, 7, 5, 5],
       [8, 8, 8, 4, 5],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```